# joint probability of two Gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution

I was studying factor analysis model using a lecture note by Prof. Andrew Ng (http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes9.pdf).

It says

$z \sim N(0,I) \\
\epsilon \sim N(0, \psi) \\
x = \mu + \Lambda z + \epsilon$

where $z \in \mathbf{R}^k, \mu \in \mathbf{R}^n, \Lambda \in \mathbf{R}^{b * k}, \psi \in \mathbf{R}^{n * n}$.

$z$ is the factor vector drawn in the latent space and $x$ is a linear combination of $z$ with Gaussian noise.

The lecture note then says that their joint distribution is also a Gaussian. That is,

$\begin{pmatrix} z\\x\end{pmatrix} \sim N(\mu_{zx}, \Sigma)$

Can somebody tell me why the joint distribution of two normal is also Gaussian? Does it generally hold? Or, does it hold only for a special case?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But, can you explain to me how the wiki article is related to the question? All the article says is that the sum of two Gaussian is Gaussian.

Comment: The link posted by M Turgeon does not answer the question.  Here's a better one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution

Comment: Most likely, somewhere above the part you quoted to us, perhaps at the beginning of the section or chapter or book, it says that for the rest of this section/chapter/book Prof Ng is assuming that $z$ and $\epsilon$ are _independent_ Gaussian vectors, probably because the _noise_ $\epsilon$ is believed to be independent of the observations $z$. That suffices to  make $x$ a Gaussian vector, and for $x$ and $z$ to be jointly Gaussian.

Answer (score 2):

It is **not** generally true that if two or more random variables are separately (or "marginally") normally distributed, then they are jointly normally distributed.

For example, suppose $X\sim N(0,1)$ and
$$
Y = \begin{cases} \phantom{-}X & \text{if }|X|<1, \\ -X & \text{if }|X|\ge 1. \end{cases}
$$
Then $Y\sim N(0,1)$ as well, but the distribution of the pair $(X,Y)$ is not a $2$-dimensional normal distribution.  Notice that the pair is constrained to lie within a union of three line segments that are not all colinear.  But a $2$-dimensional normal distribution is constrained to lie on a line only when its variance is a singular matrix, and otherwise is supported on the entire plane.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then, under what condition is joint probability of two Gaussian Gaussian? The case in my posting seems be in that case.

Comment: It is Gaussian if, and only if, they are both linear combinations of some Gaussian random variables that are independent.  That includes, but is not limited to, the case in which the two Gaussians are themselves independent.  So for example, suppose $U$ and $V$ are independent.  Then $U$, $V$ are jointly Gaussian, and so are the two random variable $U+2V$ and $5U-6V$, although those are not independent.  Another equivalent way of looking at its is that $U,V$ are jointly Gaussian precisely if every linear combination $aU+bV$ has a $1$-dimensional Gaussian distribution.

Comment: . . . . where $a,b$ are "constant", i.e. not random.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. So, then, in the case of Factor Analysis, I guess that $z$ and $\epsilon$ are independent and that $x$ is a linear combination of $z$ and $\epsilon$. So, (x,z) is Gaussian. Am I right?

Comment: I also have another question. Does this test -- using U and V -- also generalize to N variables where N >=3. That is, if $X_i = a_i U + b_i V$ where 1<=i<=N, is $(X_1 X_2 ... X_n)$ a multivariate joint Gaussian?

Comment: Yes. ${{{{{}}}}}$ ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

See this link: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gaussianprocess/node7.html

It proves that if x is gaussian, x = (x1 x2), then x1 is gaussian and x2/x1 is gaussian. The inverse also holds true.